# Blaze Meteor dynamically instanciate template and datacontext

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm dynamically instanciating template on event / or array change (with observe-like functionality).

To achieve that, I use

```
//whatever event you want, eg:
$(".foo").on("click", function(){
    Blaze.renderWithData(Template.widgetCard, d, $(".cards").get(0));
}
```

That is working, but obviously, instances aren't bound to any parent's template.

Because I just rendered this template on the `div.cards` I'm unable to use the `Template.parentData(1)` to get the parent datacontext, even so this `div.cards` is include on a template.

The quick fix would be to set the wanted reference (which in my case is an object) variable parent's datacontext on global scope, or even use Session, or directly pass this context through the renderWithData's data.

Do you know any other way,even better the proper one (I mean Meteor fancy one), to achieve that?
Is it a good `Blaze.renderWithData` use case?

Tell me if i'm unclear or more code is needed.

**EDIT:**

Complementary context info:

I've a chart (d3) where it's possible to select some parts of it.
It has an array property to stock this selected data part.

```
Chart = function Chart(clickCb, hoverCb, leaveCb, addSelectionCb, removeSelectionCb){
  var chart = this;
  chart.selectedParts = [];
  //... code
}
```

From outside of this Chart class (so on the Meteor client side), the `chart.selectedParts` is modified (add/delete).

The dream would be to "bind" this array `chart.selectedParts` like:

```
Template.templateContainingAllThoseCards.helpers({
    selectedDataChart: function(){
        return Template.instance.chart.selectedParts;
    },
    //...
});
```

and on the template being able to do something like that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="cards">
            {{#each selectedDataChart}}            
                {{> cardWidget}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like that, if the `chart.selectedParts` was reactive, Blaze could automatically create or remove `cardWidget` template instance due to the binding.

I've tried to use `manuel:reactivearray` package on it (and it's kind of anoying cause I'm doing complex manipulation on this array with Underscore, which obviously don't work with none-native Array type such reactiveArray).
Not working, but I dunno if it should have worked.

What do you think?

At this time, I'm doing things a bit dirty I suppose; I juste instanciate/destroying Blaze View on element added/removed `chart.selectedParts` as: `Blaze.renderWithData(Template.widgetCard, {data: d, chart: this}, $(".cards").get(0));`

Comment: I feel like more code is needed.  In my head I feel like this would be a case where you want a reactive var triggered onClick to make the widgetCard template load in...

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure a reactive var shall be the good way, but things are little bit more complicated. I will edit the question with more detail to show you.

Answer (score 0):

So here how I manage to do that.

Actually I don't think using Blaze.renderWithData() is a good solution.

Best way I've found is to pass your data on "Reactive mode", to be able to use all Template functionalities, and keep using Spacebars to instanciate templates. (Like parent DataContext link).

Easiest way to have reactive datasource is to always match your data with your Mongo, so I don't have to declare a custom Reactive Data source (which could be tricky with complex from a complex js data structure).

If someone have the same problem, I'm pretty sure it's because you don't follow the "good" way to do (which was my case).

One con with always updating your DB as reactive Data source should be a case where you're doing a lot of UI state change, and after all, saving the change. On this case, it's pretty useless to always pass by the DB, but it's from far the quickest solution.

Ask me if you have any similar issue understanding philosophy/way to do, I'm starting to understand what i'm doing!